# sbt + Intellij IDEA: dependencies from git?

Tags: git, scala, libgdx, sbt, scalameter

I am trying to manage my projects dependencies with sbt and I am having trouble with getting things from GitHub. I tried doing a kind of multi-project-dependency something or other, but that just broke what I already had. My end goal is being able to fetch things from GitHub along with sbt plug-ins and generate an Intellij IDEA project.

I've searched high and low, but maybe not high/low enough. Thanks for your help. I am new at this.

**Here's a gist of my build.scala**: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4178a90a7c7ccfe3856
**And a gist of the output of "sbt update"**: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d10caeaf361a7399a7f

Answer (score 1):

I see problems with scalameter and scalamock-scalatest-support.

Try the following:

- Use this dependency for scalameter:

  "com.github.axel22" % "scalameter_2.10" % "0.3"

  But this is only a workaround. Normally your scala version (2.10) should be used
  correctly if you use %%.
- Add the sonatype release repository to your build (like you did for the snapshot repository).

By the way: There is a newer scalameter version available (0.4).